# CRUD Genérico no Entity Framework com entidade não especificada

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, genéricos

Estou tentando fazer um CRUD Genérico para meu projeto. Entretanto como usei DataBaseFirst não vejo como ter uma classe genérica de Entidade que possa ser herdada. Pois não faz o menor sentido, eventualmente quando eu atualizar o banco, teria que entrar em todas as mais de 60 classes das tabelas e adicionar a herança novamente. Quero as classes de entidade que o Entity Framawork gerou puras, tais como foram geradas.

Sendo assim estou tentando algo como:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas como podem ver tenho esse problema da propriedade não estar definida, já que como disse não quero ter nada parecido com uma "EntidadeGeral".

Alguém sabe de alguma maneira de conseguir isso? Tipo tem alguma classe que o Entity utiliza por baixo dos panos que possa ser usada na restrição *where*. Ou talvez se ao invés de Generics eu usasse Reflection? Alguma ideia?

**Editado:** Código Adicionado.

```
public class DaoEF<TEntity> : IDaoEF<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    public GPSdEntities _dbContext { get; set; } = new GPSdEntities();


    public async Task<TEntity> GetById(int id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
                    .AsNoTracking()
                    .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }
```

Comment: publique o código e não uma imagem dele, ficá mais dinâmico a ajuda.

Comment: Código adicionado... Queria mostrar o erro, por isso a imagem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiro, `CRUD` genérico o `Entity Framework` já possui, o mesmo se chama `DbSet<T>`.

Segundo ponto, vejo que você quer abusar do `AsNoTracking`, isto vai lhe trazer mais problemas do que ganho, então aconselho que não encapsule ele, deixe que o desenvolvedor decida o momento de usa-lo.

Terceiro ponto, se tudo que precisa, é escrever consultas reaproveitáveis, então estenda o `DbContext`. Da forma como você está fazendo, terá múltiplos Contextos trabalhando na mesma unidade de trabalho.

```
public static class EFExtensions<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public static async Task<TEntity> GetById<TEntity>(this GPSdEntities context, int id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<TEntity>()
            .AsNoTracking()
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(e => e.Id == id);
    }
}
```

Agora respondendo a sua pergunta, as classes geradas de forma automática são todas parciais, então digamos que você tenha uma classe como a seguinte.:

```
public partial class MinhaClass
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

você poderá definir em um segundo arquivo a complementação desta classe.:

```
public partial class MinhaClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    { 

    }
}
```

inclusive você já teria de criar este arquivo/classe caso precisa-se adicionar algum atributo as propriedades geradas.:

```
public class MinhaClassMeta
{
    [Display(Name = "Propriedade 01")]
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
}


[MetadataType(typeof(MinhaClassMeta))]
public partial class MinhaClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    { 

    }
}
```

Comment: Então Tobias... Muito obrigado pela resposta. Foi precisa e completa. só pra você entender, essa classe genérica teria por objetivo ser herdada pelas classes específicas de cada tabela em uma camada de persistência, centralizando o código comum. Valew!